# Boot mac from DVD. Recovery data

Tags: macos, boot

I've messed up my mac running OSx 10.4. I could recovery it if I can access the CLI (I've accidentally moved some files from root directory to another one --> this lead not to booting anymore, keeping flashing on the logo's image). So basically I just need to move them back to the original dir.

I'm not an expert: I read on Stackoverflow that I need to press command-R while booting but it seems that my OS is too old for this trick :(

How can I solve it? Thanks in advance. Really hoping that someone will help.

PS I've tried to reboot with the installation dvd but it brings me where I can reinstall the entire OS. I just want either to access the CLI or the graphical interface.

Answer (score 2):

Boot from your CD, then press <kbd>Continue</kbd> (I believe) to get to the next screen.  You should see your menu bar pop up at the top of the screen.  There you can select the `Terminal` from the `Utilities` menu, and your mounted disk should be under `/Volumes`.

`rsync` is not available in this mode, but `scp` is.

Hope that helps.